# Auto-refresh excel sheet on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a setup on sharepoint with an excel data file linked to another excel file containing charts and pivot tables based on this first file. Both files are saved together in a shared folder. I then have a site page which contains the pivots and charts displayed as web parts. I want to be able to refresh only the data file and then see the pivot file and subsequent sit page update without having to open and click refresh on any of the files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you're using.

For SharePoint 2013, check [Configure Excel Services data refresh by using external data connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-excel-services-data-refresh-by-using-external-data-connections-in-shar)

For SharePoint online, you maycheck [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyM9hzajoRg), while this should require user logon in.